# refresh angular Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i put some ng-click in my tabs and create some function so i can rid the refresh but in turns me to refresh the whole page

*note this is slim format*

```
md-tabs ng-click="ctrl.reloadStuff()" md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-selected="ctrl.selected_index"
```

my controller

```
@loadStuff = -> 
  $route.reload()
```

but when i click the another tab my browser refresh and go back to my first tab i cant go to the second tab is there a reload tab in angular?

Comment: you are reloading the page not the tab, use 2 way databinding for your tab content

Comment: how can i reload the tab? can you help me im stack in here lol

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle or code pen?

Comment: i dont have account in angular jsfiddle